# Not getting accurate result in mongodb using gte and lte query

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

This is my `user` collection in mongodb

```
{
    "_id" : NumberLong(104060),
    "age" : 41,
    "username" : "appubhai75@gmail.com",
    "roles" : [
        "ROLE_USER"
    ],
    "firstName" : "Apurva",
    "lastName" : "Shah",
    "email" : "appubhai75@gmail.com",
    "createdDate" : ISODate("2016-02-08T12:23:02.001Z"),
}
```

i am using criteria like this

```
criteria = new Criteria().orOperator(name, email)
            .andOperator(genderCriteria).and("_id").ne(id).and("createdDate").gte(startDate).lte(endDate);
```

when i am passing `startdate` and `enddate` like:

```
Start date is::2015-12-16T00:00:00.000+05:30
end date is::2016-02-08T00:00:00.000+05:30
```

this `user` is not coming ,but when i change my `enddate` to

```
end date is::2016-02-09T00:00:00.000+05:30
```

then it is coming.
 If i am using `gte` and `lte` then it must include the date equal to also .Like,when i pass the date from 16 dec to 8 feb, then it is giving all the `users` with created date 16 to 7 feb. not including the `user` with created date 8 feb,and when i am passing 16 dec to 9 feb then it include 8 feb user.Is anything am doing wrong i am confuse.Please help.
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won't get results for this

```
Start date is::2015-12-16T00:00:00.000+05:30
end date is::2016-02-08T00:00:00.000+05:30
```

Check the created Date for `user` it is `ISODate("2016-02-08T12:23:02.001Z")` date is equal but not the time.Overall your user date is not in your range .Mongo it checks for both date and time equality.

The one solution you can have is at your application side add additional time `24*60*60 - 1` to this  `Date createdDate` using `DateUtils` in `org.apache.commons.lang.time`([Apache Commons Lang](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/time/DateUtils.html))

```
DateUtils.addSeconds(createdDate,24*60*60-1);
```

**Important Assuming that you will send only date in request**.You have to add above code to pre proprocess your request object **but not when your inserting**.When ever a request comes add this piece of code.It will work fine